# Reference sorting within the .bst file

Tags: bibtex, sorting

I am using a master thesis template which was prepared from my university. But when I compile my thesis, the references are sorting alphabetically instead of by appearance in the document. I have one `.bst` file. But I couldn't find any clue about "sorting" or "ordering" in the `.bst` file. So how could I change the sorting from alphabetically to appearance order in the file from my `.bst` file ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should tell us *which* `.bst` file you use (and provide a link if it's not available at CTAN).

Comment: It's also worth noting that if your university provides a template then presumably they expect alphabetical reference sorting.

Comment: @lockstep  
here is my bib.bst file: http://gist.github.com/4335953

JosephWright yes you' re right. They mentioned in the "How to write" section, there are 2 ways to sort references that you can choose. But they didn't prepare the example for sorting appearance in the document..

Answer (score 1):

Sorting of the references is indeed controlled by the `bst` file. This is not something that you should be changing separately: Choose a `bst` file that is suited for (presumably) numeric citation style, and it will almost certainly sort by order of citation. (If you're using the name-year citation style, you should be sorting your references alphabetically as well). If you otherwise like the looks of the style you have, identify it here and ask about look-alikes.

PS. `bst` files are written in a strange stack language that I recommend you don't bother with. Unless you have a *very* strange style, you'll find the sort command about 30 lines from the bottom of the file. It looks like this:

```
SORT
```

Comment: There is not any word like sort. I can not find it. I uploaded the .bst file. You can check there: https://gist.github.com/4335953

Comment: Thanks, dude. Removing SORT command from the bst file worked for Springer splncs03.bst.

Answer (score 1):

Your bibtex style seems to be an older `makebst` style, so probably you are using the `natbib` package. To get entries sorted by order of citation, use the `unsrtnat` style. Further options are `unsrt`, and `unsrturl`.

**Edit**
Looking closer at the style file you provided, there really is no sorting going on, so you should get your references in order of citation. I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\providecommand{\bolum}{Chapter }

\begin{document}
\cite{incollection-minimal}
\cite{inbook-minimal}
\cite{article-minimal}

\bibliographystyle{Yirmidokuz}  % that is the style file you provided
\bibliography{xampl}  % this is an example bibliography that is contained in all TeX distributions
\end{document}
```

and got:

[image: pdflatex output]

As you can see, the references are in order of citation. Are you sure that you use the style file you provided?

Comment: I am using the style file at http://gist.github.com/4335953. Because it helps me to design my bibliography as my university wanted. But still I cannot the way out for sorting them by order of citation.

Comment: @Yirmidokuz I updated my answer.

Comment: yes, I am totally sure that I am using the style file provided above. The weird thing is that, in the document first citation takes the number two and the number one goes to citation of an image which is placed much after than the place of the text cited as number 2.

Comment: Wait, you have images of your document in the bibliography?! You should not do that. The bibliography is only for things that you actually *cite*, e.g., books and articles. If you want a separate list of the figures in your document, use `\listoffigures`.